If an matrix4x4 transformation would cause a triangle clockwise flipped, would the same matrix flip all the triangles?
Pretty hard for me to explain in English.
Generally I'm working on some algorithm to combine small meshes into a big one. One thing I've noticed was that if the Transform of a mesh has nagetive scale on one axis and I multiply the vertex by the Transform matrix, the face of the mesh would be flipped. Example could be easily made by using Unity UnityMeshSimplifier.MeshCombiner on a cube with negative scale on X axis.
The reason behind this was simple - for example, a triangle made by (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), which is counter-clockwise, was flipped by a matrix simply scales the x axis by -1, the result would be (-1, 0), (-2, 0), (-2, 1), which is clockwise.
So the simple solution was easily found by checking if any of triangles in the final mesh clockwise order not matching the original one.
As far as I've tested, if one triangle has clockwise order changed, all the other triangles would be the same. But I cannot proof it or disproof it. If it could be proved, I could check only the first triangle instead of all of them.
Currently I think it should work, as the normal of a triangle could only be 2 directions. Anyone could help?
The question could be simplified as: By a giving Matrix4x4 matrix which is a TRS matrix and 2 Vector3 a, b (direction). If Vector3.Cross(matrix.MultiplyVector(a), matrix.MultiplyVector(b)) == -maxtrix.MultiplyVector(Vector3.Cross(a, b)), then it works for any giving directions a and b.

Well, generally speaking, yes, even though it may sound counter intuitive. For example a triangle that is perpendicular to the flipping axis (like a triangle on the y-z plane) none of it's vertices would actually change places and the winding order would also stay the same. However if it's part of a closed volume, the triangle would still face in the wrong direction.
Imagine a mesh that is to the right of the coordinate system and a bounding triangle that is on the left side of the mesh would be facing to the left. When you flip the whole object around, the whole object would now be on the left side of the coordinate system and that same bounding triangle now closes the mesh on the right side and no longer the left side. So it should now face to the right instead of left. So it needs to be flipped as well.
Generally when you flip on an odd number of axis (1 or 3), the mesh will be inverted and the triangles need to be flipped. Only when you flip on two axis it would stay the same since each flip would need to flip the triangles around. So flipping twice would of course cancel each other.
The determinant of the matrix would tell you if it flips area / volume or not. When the determinant is negative, it would flip space, if it's positive it does not.

I could gather some info from how tangeant and bitangeant handled in shaders to support this. But I could not find a solid mathmatical proof on this. It required some understanding on the features of a TRS matrix.
